# Android does not start my Webcam in the emulator

Tags: android

I have a webcam on my machine and want to use this in the android emulator as camera replacement. I configured it in the settings of the emulator, to use the webcam0 as camera device. But it wont start when I starting the camera on the emulator. Does someone know how to enable the webcam correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[This Tutorial](http://www.ecole.ensicaen.fr/~reynaud/android/webcam_in_android_emulator.html) will be useful for doing it.please check it.